# logstash : creating multiple indices using one logstash conf file

Tags: json, postgresql, elasticsearch, nosql, logstash

I'm using logstash as a pipeline between my postgres database and elasticsearch.
I have 2 tables in my postgres database (table user and table project).
If I try to input every table on its own in seperate logstash files it works fine, but I want to use only one logstash file to create 2 indices in elasticsearch and input every postgres table data inside an index.

***My logstash file to index my project table inside elasticsearch (which works fine and creates index):***

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"     
        jdbc_password => "firas"
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\logstash-7.5.2\drivers\postgresql-42.2.10.jre6.jar"        
        jdbc_validate_connection => true               
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "select * from public.project "
        
        
        
    }
   }

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => ["project"]
  }
  stdout {}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tags in your inputs and use conditionals in your output to filter by those tags.

Your pipeline should be something like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
    *** connnection configuration for the user table ***
    tags => ["user"]
    }
    jdbc {
    *** connnection configuration for the project table ***
    tags => ["project"]
    }
}
output {
    if "user" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "user"
        }
    }
    if "project" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost:9200"
            index => "project"
        }
    }
}
```